# How bind to text dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have kendoui dropdownlist. I need bind to selected text.

source html:

```
<span style="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="Pests_listbox" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="Pests_option_selected">
     <span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default k-state-focused" unselectable="on">
     <span class="k-input" unselectable="on">Big Headed Ants</span>
     <span class="k-select" unselectable="on">
     <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" unselectable="on">select</span>
     </span>
     </span>
<input type="hidden" data-bind="events: { select: roleSelected }, value: pets.id, text: pets.name" name="Pets" id="Pets" value="ABTB" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;"></span>
```

value bind success, but text not bind =(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you should have an HTML that looks like:

```
<input name="Pets" id="Pets"
       data-text-field="name"
       data-value-field="id"
       data-bind="events: { select: roleSelected }, source: pets"
       value="ABTB" data-role="dropdownlist"/>
```

Then your JavaScript should be:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    roleSelected: function (e) {
        console.log("roleSelected", e);
    },
    pets        : [
        {id: 1, name: "name1" },
        {id: 2, name: "name2" },
        {id: 3, name: "name3" },
        {id: 4, name: "name4" },
        {id: 5, name: "name5" },
        {id: 6, name: "name6" },
        {id: 7, name: "ABTB" }
    ]
});
kendo.bind($("#Pets"), viewModel);
```

As you can see the event listener (`roleSelected`) is a function defined in the model (`viewModel`).

Comment: problam, I use remote data source

Comment: Being a remote data source should not be a problem. How does your your code look like? because what you posted in the question seems to me Kendo UI generated output not the original.